# How to resolve this error? - Class 'ViewController' has no initializers

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have created `UILabel` programmatically in swift but it gives me following error :

> Class 'ViewController' has no initializers

[image]

Code :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let lbl_LastName: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        lbl_LastName.frame = CGRectMake(10, 230, 300, 21)
        self.view.addSubview(lbl_LastName)   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change `let lbl_LastName: UILabel!` to `var lbl_LastName: UILabel!`

Comment: Correct answer, but Can you explain the solution .