# Why does let cause this error, but var does not? Class `UIViewController` has no initializers

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Alright, so I found this comment:

[How to resolve this error? - Class 'ViewController' has no initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780647/how-to-resolve-this-error-class-viewcontroller-has-no-initializers)

But no one answered the question. Why does this line cause an error:

```
let nameOfDelegate : protocolName!
```

But this one doesn't:

```
var nameOfDelegate : protocolName!
```

I understand that var is a mutable property and let is a constant, but both are being initialized, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because its not initialized, since you will need to give it a value later, you wont be able, because its a "let", so you have to make it a var so you can later initialize it

but you could use values that are already initizalized from other places - exmaple: let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate

Comment: and upvote would be nice my friend, and if you liked the others guy answer pleas mark it as accepted, help the communituy bro :D

Comment: I'm below 15 rep so I still can't upvote :/ Can you give my post an upvote so that I can upvote others? You were first so I gave you the rep.

Comment: of course. thank you my friend, and next time, don't just go to the first, go to who you think was the best answer

Answer (score 3):

In Swift optional variables are set to nil by default if you don't provide it with an initial value. Swift does not give constants default values.

Answer (score 2):

There is no init() function, so none of these class members is initialized when the class is instanciated. But only one MUST be initialized when the class is instanciated: the one that is immutable, because it will not be possible to initialize it later. Therefore, add an initalizer, in an init() function or directly on the line that defines the constant.

Comment: Of course....this made it clear for me `the one that is immutable, because it will not be possible to initialize it later.` Thanks!

Comment: The other dude was first so I had to give it to him. Thank you though!